# Is a connection between Azure AD & Azure AD B2C user accounts possible?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

We use Azure AD for our organisation's AD to manage our users. We are also setting up an Azure AD B2C environment for our external websites. As part of this we are allowing our staff to log into these sites using their windows accounts.

Is it possible to manage the staff's B2C user account from Azure AD? For example, in B2C we have setup groups. We would ideally like to be able to create new user accounts in B2C from our Azure AD, and assign users to groups. Is this possible? Or can we only manage these users from only within B2C or through using the Microsoft Graph API?

Finally, when a user is disabled in our Azure AD, would this then prevent their account being used to sign into one of our websites as that user is no longer active in the identity provider?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible if your Azure AD B2C tenant [federates with the Azure AD tenant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-add-identity-providers#add-the-azure-active-directory-identity-provider). If the user account id disabled it won't be able to sigin any application.